# Highlighted source code inline with Latex/Minted?

Tags: packages

I am using the minted package (based on pygments) to do syntax-highlighting for xml-code in my Latex documents. However I did not find an option to make it display the code inline.

```
\mint{xml}|<?xml version="1.0" ?>|
```

does a single line but does not display inside a text line. Is that achievable using minted?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not supported in the current release (minted 1.7).  There is a `\mintinline` command in the development version at https://github.com/gpoore/minted.  The development version is currently at 2.0-alpha2, but based on my own use and reports from others, it should be quite stable.