# Usage of macros inside \mintinline

Tags: macros, minted

I tried to use a macro inside `\mintinline`. This is the result:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\ab{expanded stuff}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\mintinline{\ab}

\end{document}
```

The macro `\mintinline` is introduced in version v2 alpha 2.0 (currently alpha 3, [Github link](https://github.com/gpoore/minted), and also [Highlighted source code inline with Latex/Minted?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136883/highlighted-source-code-inline-with-latex-minted) )

*Surely* there's a "better" way to do this? :-) Some solution that would also allow syntax highlighting to function as intended... (This will be a tough one because \mintinline takes up an argument, like this: `\mintinline{Python}{code goes here}`)\

I am using **minted v2.0 alpha 3**. Can be downloaded at https://github.com/gpoore/minted/tree/master/source

Comment: Why not just `\expandafter\mintinline\expandafter{\ab}`?

Comment: @Werner I get an error `Paragraph ended before \minted@inline@i was complete.` from that ???

Comment: The example doesn't compile, `\mintinline` is not defined.

Comment: @percusse I'm running `TeXworks 0.4.5 r1280` and `minted v2.0 alpha 3`, and it does compile here. :-/

Comment: OK, probably you donwloaded it separately. Also `\expandafter` works in power of two minus one. Hence, you need 1,3,7,15,31... `\expandafter`s for expansion delaying. You have 33 and frankly one should be enough as @Werner mentions. Also I recommend `listings` packge

Comment: I don't have the version of minted you mention. Provide a link so we can test.

Comment: I have added the link to the post

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let me reformat it to be readable.

```
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\mintinline{\ab}
```

Now I'll change into `\EXPANDAFTER` those that are under the effect of the first one, just to distinguish them

```
\EXPANDAFTER\expandafter\EXPANDAFTER\expandafter
\EXPANDAFTER\expandafter\EXPANDAFTER\expandafter
\EXPANDAFTER\expandafter\EXPANDAFTER\expandafter
\EXPANDAFTER\expandafter\EXPANDAFTER\expandafter
\EXPANDAFTER\expandafter\EXPANDAFTER\expandafter
\EXPANDAFTER\expandafter\EXPANDAFTER\expandafter
\EXPANDAFTER\expandafter\EXPANDAFTER\expandafter
\EXPANDAFTER\expandafter\EXPANDAFTER\expandafter
\EXPANDAFTER\mintinline{\ab}
```

The last `\EXPANDAFTER` now tries to expand the token after `\mintinline`, which is an easy job: a `{` can't be expanded. So all marked `\expandafter` tokens disappear and we're left with

```
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\mintinline{\ab}
```

Repeat as before:

```
\EXPANDAFTER\expandafter\EXPANDAFTER\expandafter
\EXPANDAFTER\expandafter\EXPANDAFTER\expandafter
\EXPANDAFTER\expandafter\EXPANDAFTER\expandafter
\EXPANDAFTER\expandafter\EXPANDAFTER\expandafter
\mintinline{\ab}
```

The last one expands (once) `\mintinline`, which, according to the definition of `\mintinline` in the package, leaves the following in the input stream:

```
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\@protected@testopt\mintinline\\mintinline{}{\ab}
```

Note that `\\mintinline` is just one token. Let's play again:

```
\EXPANDAFTER\expandafter\EXPANDAFTER\expandafter
\EXPANDAFTER\expandafter\EXPANDAFTER\expandafter
\@protected@testopt\mintinline\\mintinline{}{\ab}
```

Here `\@protected@testop` is expanded once; its definition in the LaTeX kernel is

```
% latex.ltx, line 619:
\def\@protected@testopt#1{%%
  \ifx\protect\@typeset@protect
    \expandafter\@testopt
  \else
    \@x@protect#1%
  \fi}
```

so, after removing the already used `\expandafter` tokens and replacing the expanded macro, the input stream has

```
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\ifx\protect\@typeset@protect\expandafter\@testopt
\else\@x@protect\mintinline\fi\\mintinline{}{\ab}
```

The first `\expandafter` expands the third, which in turn expands `\ifx`; since we are in a “normal” place, the test is true, so we're left with

```
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@testopt
\else\@x@protect\mintinline\fi\\mintinline{}{\ab}
```

The first `\expandafter` expands the third, which expands `\else`; this is easy: everything up to and including the matching `\fi` disappears:

```
\expandafter\@testopt\\mintinline{}{\ab}
```

Now `\\mintinline` is expanded; but its definition is

```
> \\mintinline=\long macro:
[#1]#2->\minted@resetoptcmd \setkeys {minted@optcmd}{#1}\def \minted@lang {#2}
\begingroup \let \do \@makeother \dospecials \catcode `\{=1 \catcode `\}=2 
\catcode `\ =\active \@ifnextchar \bgroup {\minted@inline@iii }{\catcode 
`\{=12\catcode `\}=12 \minted@inline@i }.
```

according to how LaTeX handles commands defined with an optional argument. Since `\\mintinline` ***wants*** a `[` after it, the error

```
! Use of \\mintinline doesn't match its definition.
\mintinline ...@testopt \mintinline \\mintinline {
                                                  }
```

is issued.

Are there better ways to do it? Yes, for example remembering the syntax of `\mintinline`:

```
\mintinline[<options>]{<language>}{<verbatim material>}
```

That string of 33 `\expandafter` tokens is simply absurd: this, instead, will do:

```
\begingroup\def\temp{\endgroup\mintinline{c}}% use your preferred language
\expandafter\temp\expandafter{\ab}
```

However, if `\ab` is thought to contain special characters, they might not get treated specially, because they have already been tokenized.

Comment: Now I am really expanded ;-)

Answer (score 5):

According to the [`minted` documentation](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/blob/master/source/minted.pdf), the syntax for `\mintinline` is:

```
\mintinline[<options>]{<language>}<delim><code><delim>
```

It seems you're short an argument - the language specification:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\ab}{expanded stuff}
\newcommand{\pythoninline}{\mintinline{python}}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\expandafter\pythoninline\expandafter{\ab}

\end{document}
```