# Undefined control sequence \mintinline

Tags: minted

I want to write inline `mysql` code with `minted`. However, there is an error `Undefined control sequence \mintinline`.

This is MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside, 12pt]{memoir}
% подешавање српског језика и ћирилице
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[Script=Cyrillic]{serbian}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Times New Roman}
\let\cyrillicfonttt\ttfamily

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,upgreek}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{layouts}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{minted}

\newtcblisting{sql}[1][]{%
  colback=white,
  listing only,
  minted options={
    fontsize=\small
  },  
  minted language=mysql,
  #1
}

\usemintedstyle{tango}

\begin{document}

\begin{sql}
SELECT *
FROM Korisnik;
\end{sql}

Koristimo tabelu \mintinline{mysql}{Korisnik}.

\end{document}
```

If I delete the line with `\mintinline`, everything else works.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136883/highlighted-source-code-inline-with-latex-minted  Perhaps it is a version issue.

Comment: You are right. It is a version issue. It works now. Thank You for pointing it out.